# Where do arbitrary phases of wavefunctions go under second-quantization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, second-quantization, anticommutator

As far as I understand, a second-quantized operator in QFT or condensed matter represents a many-body wavefunction (symmetrized for bosons or antisymmetrized for fermions). But every wavefunction is indeterminate up to a constant phase factor. Where do these phases go under second quantization? Are they 'contained' in the creation and annihilation operators? Or are they external, or dealt with some other way?

Say you want to compare two fermion operators $f^\dagger$ and $g^\dagger$, to find whether they represent orthogonal states $f^\dagger|0\rangle$ and $g^\dagger|0\rangle$ or not (orthogonal wavefunctions). If those two operators are linear combinations of other operators, e.g. $ f^\dagger =  a_1 c_1^\dagger + a_2 c_2^\dagger $ and $g^\dagger =  b_1 c_1^\dagger + b_2 c_2^\dagger $, where $\{c^\dagger_1,c_2\}=0$, how does taking the anticommutator for fermions ($\{f^\dagger,g\}$) take account of the phases of the different components of the state each operator represents? Should these phases be contained in coefficients $a_1, a_2, b_1$, and $b_2$?

It also puzzles me that if you take a unitary transformation of operators to diagonalize a (complex) Hamiltonian,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} f^\dagger_{+} \\ f^\dagger_{-} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b^* & a^* \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} \\ c^\dagger_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, there still seems to be an overall indeterminacy in phase factor of $a$ and $b$, i.e.

$$ H = \begin{pmatrix} f^\dagger_{+} & f^\dagger_{-} \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} E_+ & 0 \\ 0 & E_- \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} f_{+} \\ f_{-} \end{pmatrix} \\
     = \begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} & c^\dagger_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} |a|^2E_+ + |b|^2E_- & ab^*(E_+-E_-) \\ a^*b(E_+-E_-) & |b|^2E_+ + |a|^2E_- \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} c_{\uparrow} \\ c_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix},
$$
so that only the phase of $ab^*$ matters, not individual phases of $a$ and $b$. This seems to imply to me that the phases should be dealt with externally, and are *not* contained in the operators; however I don't think I have seen this done in practice, it seems like arbitrary phases just get ignored.

Comment: "Say you want to compare two (second-quantized) operators, to find whether they represent orthogonal states or not." -- How do you associate an operator with a state in this context?

Comment: @Andrew I suppose for an operator $f^\dagger$, I mean the state $f^\dagger|0\rangle$, where $|0\rangle$ is the 'vacuum'.

Comment: In that case, one thought is that you can absorb an arbitrary phase into the definition of the vacuum state.

Comment: @Andrew Do you know of a good reference on that? (I have a result on orthogonality/similarity of two operators, which explicitly depends on the arbitrary phases from diagonalization, and am trying to make sense of it.) Thanks.